# How to extract the certain number and certain type of string following same pattern in an efficient way?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract the year and the title from the publication records under the same pattern (author list. year. Title. Journal.)

For example for the following publication records `text`:

```
text=['Axley, J. 1988. Progress Toward a General Analytical Method for Predicting Indoor Air Pollution in Buildings: Indoor Air Quality Modeling Phase III Report. Gaithersburg, Maryland: National Bureau of Standards, NBSIR 88-3814.',
 'Bearg, D.W. 1994. Second Generation Demand-Controlled Ventilation Systems. Proceedings of ASHRAE IAQ 94: 169-174.',
 'Berg-Munch, B., G. Clausen and P.O. Fanger. 1986. Ventilation Requirements for the Control of Body Odor in Spaces Occupied by Women. Environment International 12: 195-199.']
```

The expected outputs will be
`['1988','1994','1986']` and
`['Progress Toward a General Analytical Method for Predicting Indoor Air Pollution in Buildings: Indoor Air Quality Modeling Phase III Report', 'Second Generation Demand-Controlled Ventilation Systems', 'Ventilation Requirements for the Control of Body Odor in Spaces Occupied by Women']`

I am trying to use the regular function. My code is lengthy but could extract the expected outputs. I would like to know how to do this in an efficient way.

```
newline=[]
for line in range(len(text)):
    key=text[line]
    p1=r"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\..+?\."    
    pattern1 = re.compile(p1)
    newline.append("".join(pattern1.findall(key)))
year = [x.split('.')[0] for x in newline] 
title = [y.split('.')[1] for y in newline]
```

Comment: Are you familiar with capturing brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 capturing groups:

```
\s(\d{4})\.\s*(.+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FtzXeo/1)

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `\s`: Match a whitespace
- `(\d{4})`: Match 4 digits in capture group #1
- `\.`: Match a dot
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `(.+)`: Match 1+ of any any character in capture group #2

**Code:**

```sh
>>> import re
>>> text=['Axley, J. 1988. Progress Toward a General Analytical Method for Predicting Indoor Air Pollution in Buildings: Indoor Air Quality Modeling Phase III Report. Gaithersburg, Maryland: National Bureau of Standards, NBSIR 88-3814.',
 'Bearg, D.W. 1994. Second Generation Demand-Controlled Ventilation Systems. Proceedings of ASHRAE IAQ 94: 169-174.',
 'Berg-Munch, B., G. Clausen and P.O. Fanger. 1986. Ventilation Requirements for the Control of Body Odor in Spaces Occupied by Women. Environment International 12: 195-199.']

>>> years = []
>>> titles = []
>>> for s in text:
...     m = re.search(r'\s(\d{4})\.\s*(.+)', s)
...     if (m):
...             years.append(m.group(1))
...             titles.append(m.group(2))
...
>>> print (years)
['1988', '1994', '1986']
>>> print (titles)
[
'Progress Toward a General Analytical Method for Predicting Indoor Air Pollution in Buildings: Indoor Air Quality Modeling Phase III Report. Gaithersburg, Maryland: National Bureau of Standards, NBSIR 88-3814.',
'Second Generation Demand-Controlled Ventilation Systems. Proceedings of ASHRAE IAQ 94: 169-174.',
'Ventilation Requirements for the Control of Body Odor in Spaces Occupied by Women. Environment International 12: 195-199.'
]
```

Comment: it is concise and straightfoward!